# In R, How do you separate data in a column of a data frame based on data from another column?

Tags: r

I have a data set with a number of survey variables. I am looking at the data of one column, but need to split it by the factors in another column. The survey asked gender, and also asked how much the person smoked. I need to compare how much males smoke vs females, but I cannot figure out how to split the data in the column based on the information in another column.

Can someone help?

Comment: It would be easier if you were to  post some of your data using `dput`

Comment: This sounds like a job for `dplyr::group_by() %>% dplyr::summarise()`, but I'd need an example dataset and an example your desired output in order to give you an actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want:

```
#some reproduciable data
survey <- data.frame(gender=c('m','m','f','m','f','f','m','m','f'),
           smoke=c('little','much','much','little','no','some','little','little','much'))
#gender VS smoke:
table(survey)
#or:
table(survey$gender,survey$smoke)
```